# Javascript: instantiate an object with chain calling new

Tags: javascript, class, instantiation

is it possible to instantiate an object with chain calling new on it?

I was reading a source code that did that but it was fairly confusing.

```
var SomeObject = function() {};
SomeObject.new.Sometask;
```

any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, you can do this. I have no idea *why* one might want to do this, but since Javascript is so flexible, it's possible to do most things. Maybe there's an interesting use case.

You can make `new` a getter function on the `SomeObject` then when you access `new` return a newly instantiated object:

```js
var SomeObject = function() {
    this.name = "Test"
};
// defined new getter
Object.defineProperty(SomeObject, "new", {
    get: function my_new() {
        return new SomeObject()
    }
});

// add Sometask
SomeObject.prototype.Sometask = function(){
    console.log("name:", this.name)
    return this // to allow more chaining
}

SomeObject.new.Sometask();
```

Answer (score 1):

The OOP in your example is a little off. It looks to be a blend of traditional functional programming with JavaScript and elements of actual OOP. When talking about instantiation of objects in JavaScript, for the sake of clarity, I would refer to the syntax outlined by Mozilla here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS

With regards to your question, you can chain a method after instantiating an object just as you can immediately retrieve a property on that newly instantiated object.

```
var person1 = new Person('Bob');
console.log(person1.name);
```

Or get the property immediately after instantiation:

```
console.log((new Person('Bob')).name);
```

The same can be done with methods:

```
var person2 = new Person('Bob', 23);
console.log(person2.getAge());
```

Or call the method immediately after instantiation:

```
console.log((new Person('Bob', 23)).getAge());
```

Comment: I agree with the statement that you made, but I just saw this in a source code and I'm trying to understand what they're doing.